# Getting an element to share a background with another element?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I have a document that is styled like so:

```
<div class = 'page'>
  <header class = 'site-header'>
  <div class = 'main-navigation-container'>
      ...
  </div>
  </header>
</div>
```

where the `header` has a nice `background-image`. However, as soon as the `header` ends we reach the navigation bar, which has a stock blue option. I want to have the `header` background "spill over" into the 
`.main-navigation-container`, so that it appears as if the `.main-navigation-container` is contained within the `header`.

Here's the idea:

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmLAl.png)

As you can see in the before, the navigation container (menu) does not share the background with the header. However, after the change it should look like this:

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYJ5T.png)

Notice that the menu is now changed to be located within the header. The issue lies in the fact that I am using Wordpress for the backend, so I had to add javscript to the body as opposed to redefining the html elements manually:

```
<script>
  var nav = document.getElementsByClassName("main-navigation-container")[0];
  document.getElementsByClassName("site-header")[0].appendChild(nav);
</script>
```

This approach worked when I used a test document on my local machine, but it does not work in Wordpress. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I could solve my problem with either the approach I'm currently using, or an entirely different one?

Thanks.

**EDIT:
SOLVED: It was an issue with the flow of the document. When you add custom javascript in wordpress they give you two options for script location: Body and Footer. I assumed I needed to put the script in the body, but when I tried moving the script to the footer it worked.**

Comment: Can you please add some more code? It seems like your main-navigation actually IS contained within the header (which you are trying to make it look like). If it is hard to find words, maybe you can show a image of how it should look like. And the CSS would be nice because your question is stylesheet related.

Comment: If I am understanding your problem, you might be running into a race condition where you are assigning variables before the document is fully loaded.  Try wrapping your code in `window.onload` function or perhaps if you have jequery available, use `$(document).ready(function() { ... })`

Answer (score 0):

You can make the background of your nav transparent. You can add a custom class 'bg-custom' to the 'main-navigation-container', then in your CSS style sheet add:

```
.bg-custom: {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

or add it inline with a 'style' tag:

```
style="background-color: transparent;"
```

Comment: This doesnt work. When I do it I get an all white background, because the nav element is not contained within the site-header.

Comment: This would be better written as `background-color: transparent`.

Comment: @drakzuli According to your code, the 'main-navigation-container' is definitely contained in the 'site-header'. Can't help much more without seeing more code, but I would suggest (based on the imgs shared) setting the 'site header' section to have: 
`min-width: 100vw;` and `min-height: 75vh;`. That may solve some of your problems. Don't forget to check your layout with either FireFox or Chrome Dev tools in the browser to make sure you are giving all of your elements enough space. Otherwise, it will displace elements that should fit.